# Strongloop loopback. Cannot add User instance from explorer

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

I've created a model (slc loopback:model customer), done 'slc run', and browsed to http://localhost:3000/explorer/.  I see both 'customer' and 'User' models.  But I cannot figure out how to add an instance to the User model. I select 'Users->Post /Users' and provide the following data

```
{
  "realm": "",
  "username": "myname",
  "credentials": "secret",
  "challenges": [],
  "email": "scooby@do.com",
  "emailVerified": false,
  "verificationToken": "",
  "status": "",
  "created": "",
  "lastUpdated": "",
  "id": 0
}
```

The response is

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "status": 422,
    "message": "The `User` instance is not valid. Details: `password` can't be blank (value: undefined).",
    "statusCode": 422,
    "details": {
      "context": "User",
      "codes": {
        "password": [
          "presence"
        ]
      },
      "messages": {
        "password": [
          "can't be blank"
        ]
      }
    },
    "stack": "ValidationError: The `User` instance is not valid. Details: `password` can't be blank (value: undefined).
}
```

I've tried with other values for the data but cannot figure out how to resolve the 'blank password'.  Can anyone point out what I might be missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a `password` key (even though it's not listed). Do the same `POST /User`, but enter these fields in the JSON object instead:

```
{
  email: "foo@bar.com",
  password: "foobar"
}
```

These two specifically are required. The rest of the ones you've shown are optional.

Comment: Thanks very much superkhau.  This helped. I succeeded in adding an instance, and even logging in (POST /clients/login).  But I cannot seem to succeed using any of the other Explorer REST APIs.  For example, I cannot figure out the inputs for (GET /clients/count).  What value should I input for the 'where' field? I tried 'access_token=.....' but no luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing you should usually do in explorer is log the user in like you just did. Then copy paste the id/access token to the status bar filed on the top right and click "set access token". Then subsequent requests will use this token for authentication and allow you to perform other actions. Of course this also depends on the permissions set on the model, etc.

Comment: I have done what you advise, such that now my request looks like http://localhost:3000/api/clients?access_token="pjO7lLdRW2fxhnqAdJ0DgkVnZ9ML01CN5EBB5TCwBUOoowruiu55J2PdLCUanB1C".  And my json model looks like {
  "name": "client",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "weight": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": []
}  But still getting Unauthorized. Do these ACL look ok?

Comment: I'm getting the same error message when I try to update with a `PUT` a logged in user. Any tips @superkhau ?